# Codeigniter populating drop down from database

Tags: codeigniter-form-helper

Hello friends i am having a problem with codeigniter drop down list....
it is working finely but there is a problem which i m unable to solve...

coming direct to code here is my **mode**l ..

```
function getBatchId(){

$batchId = $this->db->get('batch');


$batchList = array();

if($batchId->num_rows() >0){

foreach ($batchId->result_array() as $tablerow) {
  $batchList[] = $tablerow['code'];
}

return  $batchList;


}else {return false;}
```

my **controller**

```
$this->load->model('AdmissonModel');

$content =  array(
'progid' => $this->AdmissonModel->getProgrameCode(),
'batch' => $this->AdmissonModel->getBatchId(),
'depid' => $this->AdmissonModel->getDepId()
        );



$this->load->view('Admissions/admForm_view',$content);
```

**and my view**

```
<tr>
<td>BATCH</td>
    <td><?php echo form_dropdown('Batch',$batch); ?></td>
 </tr>
```

the result produced is like this

```
<select name="Batch">
<option value="0">BCS12</option>
<option value="1">BCS14</option>
<option value="2">IMS01</option>
<option value="3">INU01</option>
<option value="4">INU02</option>
<option value="5">INU03</option>
</select>
```

now the problem is that i want the values also like BCS12,BCS14,IMS01 etc not 0,1,2,3...but the values are 0,1,2,3,4.....can any 1 help me plz...thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your model update this function to

```
function getBatchId(){

$batchId = $this->db->get('batch');


$batchList = array();

if($batchId->num_rows() >0){

foreach ($batchId->result_array() as $tablerow) {
  $batchList[$tablerow['code']] = $tablerow['code'];
}

return  $batchList;


}else {return false;}
```